# Prevent jupyter notebook to run all cells on open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook to write my code, but I'm facing a problem
that each time I open the notebook I find that all the cells are run.

This causes problems when I want to add some new cells in between.

So I am obliged to rerun the code from the beginning to get the right results.

Is there a way I can start from where I stopped running to save time? Especially since my code takes around 4 hours to run.

Comment: Well, you'd have to implement some sort of data persistence to avoid recomputing things. Otherwise, the process is gone if you shutdown the kernel. Are there some objects you could just pickle?

Comment: can you share the notebook

Comment: The confusing thing about Jupyter Notebooks is that although it persists things like console/image output, it is not persisting the actual Python interpreter itself, data, variables, etc.  For the parts of your notebook that are very slow, as others have pointed out, you should be saving the results to some kind of file alongside your notebook.  How to do that depends what you're doing.

Comment: Last I checked, all cells are not run upon opening a notebook. The cell output exists from previous runs, yes, but cells are not re-ran by default. You must have some configuration that is doing that, if so

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't shut down the computer that runs the notebook ex.: in windows
   "Lock" option
2. Run the notebook in cloud (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, Free option Google Colab runs for a while) where you don't need to shut
   down the computer
3. Save down calculated results to files like.:
   `txt, csv`
4. Save down models with `pickle`
5. It is also possible that you leave the computer stays on but the notebook gets disconnected from the environment in this case just pick your already running environment reconnect and it will have all your previous runtime results